# How to Merge two column of ASPxGridView in DevExpress?

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

I want to Merge and show the two column of the gridview as single column.

Example:

I have two different columns

```
--------------------
|Amount | Currency |
--------------------
| 1000  | INR      |
--------------------
| 2000  | EUR      |
--------------------
| 500   | USD      |
--------------------
```

Result as one column

```
-----------
|Amount   |
-----------
| 1000INR |
-----------
| 2000EUR |
-----------
| 500USD  |
-----------
```

Two columns are seperate fields from databaes.i don't want to do it in procedure, need to be done in frontend because i want to put total for this amount column.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for calculated columns.
Have a look at the following links:

- [devex unbound columns](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2007/11/29/aspxgridview-screencast-unbound-columns.aspx)
- [devex calculated columns](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q416750)